# My clear() command not working in Google Chrome JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, console

Every time I run the clear() command to clear space in my JavaScript console on Chrome, I run into the following error: VM229:1 Uncaught TypeError: clear is not a function
at :1:1
I'm aware that there are other ways to clear the console, but I'm wondering at what I'm doing wrong or if I have a weird setting enabled.

Comment: Are you typing `clear()` directly into the console?  Or are you trying to run `clear()` from a script in your page?  You may need to use `console.clear();`.

Answer (score 1):

Type `console.clear()` into the console.

The command will fail with an appropriate error if you enabled the option "preserve log".